# Remove SQL output when value IS NULL

Tags: mysql, sql

The below SQL query is working for me, but it returns the property value when there staffNo is null 6 times(Once for each staff member). I want to return the property owner even if the staffNo is null, without 6 returns.

```
SELECT s.branchNo, s.staffNo, s.fName, s.lName, propertyNo, p.staffNo,
       o.fName, o.lName, o.ownerNo
  FROM staff s, propertyforrent p, privateowner o
 WHERE s.staffNo = p.staffNo AND o.ownerNo = p.ownerNo
    OR p.staffNo IS NULL     AND o.ownerNo = p.ownerNo
 ORDER BY s.branchNo, s.staffNo, propertyNo
```

Results

```
B003    SG14    David   Ford    PG16    SG14    Tony    Shaw    CO93
B003    SG14    David   Ford    PG4     NULL    Tina    Murphy  CO40
B003    SG37    Ann     Beech   PG21    SG37    Carol   Farrel  CO87
B003    SG37    Ann     Beech   PG36    SG37    Tony    Shaw    CO93
B003    SG37    Ann     Beech   PG4     NULL    Tina    Murphy  CO40
B003    SG5     Susan   Brand   PG4     NULL    Tina    Murphy  CO40
B005    SL21    John    White   PG4     NULL    Tina    Murphy  CO40
B005    SL41    Julie   Lee     PG4     NULL    Tina    Murphy  CO40
B005    SL41    Julie   Lee     PL94    SL41    Carol   Farrel  CO87
B007    SA9     Mary    Howe    PA14    SA9     Joe     Keogh   CO46
B007    SA9     Mary    Howe    PG4     NULL    Tina    Murphy  CO40
```

Here is the desired result

```
B003    SG14    David   Ford    PG16    SG14    Tony    Shaw    CO93
B003    SG14                    PG4     NULL    Tina    Murphy  CO40
B003    SG37    Ann     Beech   PG21    SG37    Carol   Farrel  CO87
B003    SG37    Ann     Beech   PG36    SG37    Tony    Shaw    CO93
B005    SL41    Julie   Lee     PL94    SL41    Carol   Farrel  CO87
B007    SA9     Mary    Howe    PA14    SA9     Joe     Keogh   CO46
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I did that because of the OR. I wanted it to find the owner if there is a staffNo, or if a staffNo is NULL. Is there another way to state it?

Comment: can u write the wished result , i dont understand what u mean in your question

Comment: `WHERE (o.ownerNo = p.ownerNo) AND ((s.staffNo = p.staffNo) OR p.staffNo IS NULL))`. note the bracketing.

Comment: I want to see the Owners first name and last name, and the Sales persons first name and last name. However if the sales person does not exist it did not return the owners last name. Once I added the or statement for IS NULL it showed NULL 6 times. NULL should only appear once, as should Tina Murphy.

Comment: i mean can you edit your post and put the wished result in table

Comment: @AustinTheNoob what are your begin tables?

Comment: (a) Use the explicit JOIN notations, and (b) consider whether you want a LEFT OUTER JOIN — that seems likely given the OR condition, and (c) use parentheses around AND and OR compound conditions; it makes it easier to read your SQL reliably.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a left join may be helpful

```
SELECT s.branchNo, s.staffNo, s.fName, s.lName, propertyNo, p.staffNo,
       o.fName, o.lName, o.ownerNo
  FROM privateowner o
  LEFT JOIN propertyforrent p ON o.ownerNo = p.ownerNo
  LEFT JOIN staff s ON s.staffNo = p.staffNo

 ORDER BY s.branchNo, s.staffNo, propertyNo
```

Comment: I get this from your code #1054 - Unknown column 'p.staffNo' in 'on clause'

Comment: That worked! I will message you some questions I have. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT s.branchNo, s.staffNo, s.fName, s.lName, propertyNo, p.staffNo,
       o.fName, o.lName, o.ownerNo
  FROM staff AS s LEFT JOIN propertyforrent AS p
  ON s.staffNo = p.staffNo AND  p.staffNo IS NOT NULL
  LEFT JOIN privateowner AS o
 ORDER BY s.branchNo, s.staffNo, propertyNo;
```

Answer (score 1):

Hope this is correct..

```
SELECT s.branchNo, s.staffNo, s.fName, s.lName, propertyNo, p.staffNo, o.fName, o.lName, o.ownerNo
FROM staff s 
join propertyforrent p on s.staffNo = p.staffNo
left join privateowner o on o.ownerNo = p.ownerNo
where p.staffNo is not null
ORDER BY s.branchNo, s.staffNo, propertyNo
```

Is the blank columns under David Ford intentional?

Comment: It is blank because there is no staffNO for that entry. This gave me everything except the NULL entry, which I would like to return.